# Can't access value in JSON row Postgresql?

Tags: json, postgresql, psql, jsonb

## Problem

having trouble trying to get values from a json object in an sql query.
Im using postgresql.

## Code

I'm saving the data as a json type

Schema.prisma

```
model Example {
  ...
  raw  Json?
 ...
}
```

The query for the row correctly return json

```
SELECT
   ex.raw
FROM 
   "Example" ex
```

```
{"type":"Eg","device":"Eg","value":1,"timestamp":"2024-02-23T05:51:19Z"}
```

But then trying to access the data return rows of null

```
SELECT
   ex.raw->>'type'
FROM 
   "Example" ex
```

## Have tried

Casting to json & jsonb

```
SELECT
   ex.raw::json->>'type'
FROM 
   "Example" ex
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: The SQL part works fine, can't reproduce it. Since you didn't share all the relevant code, we can't help you with that.

Comment: `SELECT ex.raw->>'type' FROM "Example" ex ORDER BY 1 NULLS LAST;` - your client might be showing you some initial records that don't have that key.

Answer (score 0):

My bet is that the DB client you're inspecting this in is showing you only a few records, none of which have that key, which is why you get the `null`s. Here's how I would reproduce it: [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/fi-no-BA)

```
create table "Example" (raw json);
insert into "Example" select null from generate_series(1,2e3);
insert into "Example" values
('{"type":"Eg","device":"Eg","value":1,"timestamp":"2024-02-23T05:51:19Z"}')
returning jsonb_pretty(raw::jsonb);
```

| jsonb_pretty |
| --- |
| { "type": "Eg", "value": 1, "device": "Eg", "timestamp": "2024-02-23T05:51:19Z" } |

And here's something PGAdmin, DataGrip, DBeaver could be doing: adding a `LIMIT` clause at the end (or just displaying a long list, and you just need to scroll down). Since I populated the table with 2000 null entries first, I won't necessarily see the value I entered after those.

```
SELECT
   ex.raw->>'type'
FROM 
   "Example" ex
LIMIT 3;
```

| ?column? |
| --- |
| *null* |
| *null* |
| *null* |

If you ask to order `nulls last`, you'll get the non-empties first.

```
SELECT
   ex.raw->>'type'
FROM 
   "Example" ex
ORDER BY 1 NULLS LAST
LIMIT 3;
```

| ?column? |
| --- |
| **Eg** |
| *null* |
| *null* |